# Map SQL *ROWS* to Java bean fields

Tags: java, sql, mapping, javabeans

I know there are a lot of libraries that map SQL table columns to bean fields, but we are integrating a legacy database that has an extensive 'config table', which looks like `id,name,type,value`, for example a row may look like:

`('24234','RunTest','boolean','true')`

I was hoping there was a library or tool out there that would allow us to maybe annotate a java bean with mappings of fields to rows, since it seems to be a common enough use case. Any ideas ?

Comment: Hibernate is your best choice.

Comment: I would suggest you try Spring Framework with Hibernate. Take a look at the following api docs
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html

Comment: Neither Hibernate nor Spring seem to have the option to do what I'm looking for. Again, I'm looking for a way to map rows to FIELDS, not to classes.

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible, but you might need to create composite classes to handle the different fields.